# Congruence equation problem [verification]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, congruences

Solve the equation $144x\equiv24\mod228$ giving all the integer and not congruent solutions.

So, there's solution for this equation if and only if $(228:144)=d\implies d|24$

By the Extended Euclidean Algorithm:
$d=12 \implies 12|24$, then it can be solved.

Solving (...)

$228 = 1 \times 144 + 84$

$144 = 1 \times 84 + 60$

$84 = 1 \times 60 + 24$

$60 = 2 \times 24 + 12$

$24 = 2 \times 12 + 0$

Clearing the rests:

$84 = 228-1\times 144$

$60 = 144 \times84$

$24=84-1 \times60$

$12=60-2\times 24$

let $r,s\in\Bbb Z$ then $12 = r\times144+s\times228$

Replacing:
$$12=60-2\times24$$
$$12=60-2\times[84-1\times60]$$
$$12=3\times60-2\times84$$
$$12=3\times[144-1\times84]-2\times84$$
$$12=3\times144-5\times84$$
$$12=3\times144-5[228-1\times144]$$
$$=8\times144-5\times228$$

But $24=2\times12+0 \implies 24=2\times[8\times144-5\times228]+0\implies24=16\times144-10\times228$

then, $x_0=16$ and $t={m\over{d}}={228\over{12}}=19$

Not congruent solutions: $x_0+q\times t=16+19\times q$ with $q=1,...,11$

Integer solutiuons: $m\times k + (x_0+q\times k) = 228\times k + [16 + q \times 19]$ with $k \in \Bbb Z$

I'm not sure about the solutions, so my question is: this is well done?. If not, someone can recommend some book or information to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Divide through by 12 and reduce the problem to,

$(2)$ $12x \equiv 2\mod 19$

$(3)$ Here, $\gcd(12,19) = 1$. And $1|2$ so we are good.

$(4)$ Now, $12(8)+19(-5)=1$ (by $\textbf{ext euclidean algorithm}$),

$(5)$ $\Rightarrow 1 \equiv 12(8)\mod 19 \Rightarrow x \equiv 12x (8)\mod 19$ (multiply by $\textbf{x}$).

Hence, $x\equiv 16 \mod 19$.